# Dropdown change event calling on pageload instead of actual click change

Tags: jquery

I have a need to post data back to the server with and AJAX call when any of multiple(1 to many) dropdowns are changed on the page by the user. The problem is that when the dropdowns are populated on page load i think its firing the change event in my jquery. Because I am getting a null error page mentioning the `AJAXUpdateAttendance` from the server before the page finishes loading.

this is what the dropdown looks like:

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(Function(m) m(i).Completed_Class, New SelectList(ViewBag._status), New With {.data_regId = currentItem.staff_id, .data_IsStaff = "true", .data_CourseRef = currentItem.course_ref, .class = "attendDrop", .data_url = Html.Action("AJAXUpdateAttendance", "Admin")})
```

Jquery

```
$(function(){
   $(".attendDrop").on("change keyup").change(function () {

        var isStaff = $(this).attr('data-IsStaff');

        if (isStaff) {
            var classId = $(this).attr('data-CourseRef');
            var regId = $(this).attr('data-regId');
            var url = $(this).attr("data-url");
            var sval = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: {isStaff: isStaff, regId: regId, classId: classId, sVal: sval},
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data.message);
                }
            });
          });
});
```

Comment: Can you place a "debugger;" statement in the body of your event handler and see when/if it is called?

Comment: try putting your jquery code in side a document.ready, maybe then it will not fire a change event when your razor code sets the currently selected option

Comment: is $(function(){}); not the same thing as document.ready?

Comment: or simply check for null in your server side method and dont do anything if the values you are expecting are null

Comment: @erikrunia checking for nulls at server side seems like im taking a wasted trip to the server.

Comment: yes they are the same, sorry didnt notice that tere

Comment: @Kolban its being called during page loading. because the error message mentions the AJAXUpdateAttendance method:  The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'isStaff' of non-nullable type 'System.Boolean' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult AJAXUpdateAttendance(Boolean, Int32, System.String, System.String)'

Comment: its not a wasted trip if you check for null in the jquery, and don't even call the server.  you have the values there... so check there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

technically you're rendering a select and then "changing" the value by setting the value from the database (or some default value).  So just check in your javascript before making the call, you didnt say which variables couldnt be null, so i'm assuming its data-regId below for sake of example:

```
$(function(){
   $(".attendDrop").on("change keyup").change(function () {

        var isStaff = $(this).attr('data-IsStaff');

        if (isStaff) {
            var classId = $(this).attr('data-CourseRef');
            var regId = $(this).attr('data-regId');
            var url = $(this).attr("data-url");
            var sval = $(this).val();
            if (regId != null) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    data: {isStaff: isStaff, regId: regId, classId: classId, sVal: sval},
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data.message);
                    }
                });
            }
          });
});
```

also, one of the perks of using data attributes with jquery is you can use

`$(this).data('courseRef')` when data attribute is `"data-course-ref"`

you can also just set a var like:

```
var dataAtts = $(this).data();
```

and then use it like an object like so:  `dataAtts.courseRef, dataAtts.regId`, etc.  but dont quote my syntax on that.. could be off a bit  :-)